# Can we start 2 sprints simultaneously with same product backlog in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, devops, azure-devops-extensions, devops-services

I need to start 2 sprints simultaneously with same product backlog in azure devops .Is that possible?
Anyone Please help !

Comment: Hi did you get a chance to check out below workaround, how did it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid Azure devops doesnot support this feature yet. [Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365438/allow-multiple-current-iterations-for-multiple-ite.html) is a similar new feature request that has been submitted to microsoft development team. You can vote it up or [create a new user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) of your own.

You can create different teams as workaround currently. Then you can configure the area path and iteration path for each team. Please check below documents for more information.

[Add a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

[Define area paths and assign to a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

[Define Iteration Paths and configure team iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

After you have added different teams and configured their area path and interation path, Select the corresponding Area path/Iteration path for the workitems.

[image]

So now different teams can have sprints start simultaneously. You can use team selector within the breadcrumbs to switch between the sprints view.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can’t do it unless you use two areas path, one for each team, both using the same iteration/sprint.